# Text input wraps onto 2 lines

Tags: css, mobile-safari

Im seeing some strange behavior on my text inputs, they are wrapping on to 2 lines when the text is too long.

They have padding and are 100% width. If I remove either of these 2 CSS rules the text stops wrapping.

I cant put my actual site live and when I try and recreate the issue (eg with jsfiddle) I cant recreate it. Here are screen shots from my iPhone:

[image]

What could be causing this? This is not default behavior but the padding and 100% width are required from my design, so I need to find another way of preventing the wrapping.

UPDATE As I said I cant recreate the issue. My attempt is below. Ive used chrome dev tools to copy all the CSS rules, and the html is the same, however the result does not wrap.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uHCav

```
<div class="cont">
<div class="one">
<input placeholder="Middle name" type="text" maxlength="40" name="middle" id="edit-middle" size="60" value="" >
  </div>
  </div>

.cont {
  background: grey;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px
}
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {

  border-left-color: #e35235 !important;

}
input {
  border-left-style: solid;
border-left-color: #c9d8e6;
border-left-width: 6px !important;
font-size: 1.2em;
border-top: none !important;
border-bottom: none !important;
border-right: none !important;
}
input {
  background: white;
}
input {
  padding: 15px 37px 15px 14px;
}
input {
  margin: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
background-color: transparent;
}
input {
  font-weight: 300;
}
input {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #19465e;
}
input {
  color: #19465e;
}

.one {
  margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using `<input type="text" .. >`?

Comment: Could you add the exact CSS rules you have for these text boxes? Also any inherited CSS.

Comment: Yes they are <input type="text" .. >

Comment: @cephalopodMD I dont get the same result when I try to recreate the example with the same CSS and HTML.

Comment: `white-space:nowrap`?

Comment: @jdln can you provide us with the `html` and `css` or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).. theres only so far we can get looking at an image.

Comment: @jdln I get that you can't reproduce it, but we still need to see it.

Comment: @jdln is there a live link you can show perhaps?

Comment: Check (or set) the text-overflow css property. Regards,

Comment: I am not sure, just try to give white-space: nowrap; to the input.

Comment: Why `appearance: none;`? From what i see its not correct value for this attribute.

Comment: Are you sure that the input remains an <input> type? Is there any chance that an external js library is converting the input to a different type?

Comment: which browser do you use in ur mobile. Some browsers like UC browser or the new opera browser does this to facilitate easier inputs

Comment: This can't be an input, the input doesn't have this behavior. It's maybe a div with contenteditable, or textarea.
Or maybe your browser changes style when input has the focus and you can't modify that.

Comment: *Please*, give us a link to the **original** page causing this. Otherwise, you will get no relevant/useful help.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or some framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by paring back your document.

**Create a new (blank) page with just the basics**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="one">
            <input placeholder="Middle name" type="text" maxlength="40" name="middle" id="edit-middle" size="60" value="" >
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Simplify your inputs CSS, just the basics**

```
input {
    font-size:1.2em;
    background:#DDD;
    padding:15px 37px 15px 14px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

You will notice the input will not wrap and you still have `width: 100%;` and padding.

Add the rest of your document one bit at a time:

1. Javascript - check that there is no problem with input
2. The rest of your CSS - check that there is no problem with input
3. Any remaining styles for your input - check that there is no problem with input
4. Any missing HTML - check that there is no problem with input

Put the jigsaw back together one piece at a time and clean up your code as you go.

Comment: It could also be useful to run your CSS through [a markup cleaner](http://www.dirtymarkup.com/) of some kind.

Comment: Excellent debugging advice, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Quite right it doesn't. Indirectly it might, though; and when i posted this answer it had been unanswered for a day or two. Thought i would bend the rules. Flag for deletion if you must.

Answer (score 8):

You might have a `word-break` property that your input is inheriting. Try adding `word-break: normal;` to the input.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `width:100%` to `position:absolute; left:0; right:0;` if you need a quick and dirty fix for this.  Just ensure that your container div then has the appropriate rules.

As a side note, it's really bad practice to have all those input rules in separate style blocks.  Try consolidating those into one, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of issues are related to the box-sizing context. You can try to define a border context for your input to ignore the padding calculation:

```
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Box sizing of border-box doesn't ignore the padding calculation, it just uses the defined width as the outer bounds of the element.  Padding will still be added to the element, except with `box-sizing:border-box` the text would have even less space.